# Can and should you loop over query returns from sub-query?

Tags: mysql

I have a query that returns the employee ID of employees that have a specific skill at a company.

```
SELECT competences.employee_id
FROM competences
WHERE service_id = 2)
```

Returns

```
1
2
4
7
```

I now want to use this query return to find the names of these employees 
from the employees table. I've tried this, which of course didn't work, but can figure out how to do it.

```
SELECT employee.first_name, employee.last_name
FROM employee
WHERE employee.employee_id = 
(SELECT competences.employee_id
FROM competences
WHERE service_id = 2)
```

How do I use the sub-query to get the employees?

Comment: Why don't you just join the tables instead?

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for `JOIN`. You should read about JOIN. Many tutorials are available. [Here is one](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/).

Try something like this:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT employee.first_name, employee.last_name
   FROM employee
   JOIN competences ON employee.employee_id = competences.employee_id
  WHERE competences.srvice_id = 2
```

Using `IN` yields the same results as `JOIN`. But it uses a so-called dependent subquery, which can be very bad for performance when your tables get large. `DISTINCT` removes any possible duplicate employee names. If we knew the names and meanings of the columns we could offer more specific advice for generating the most useful query.

Comment: I've now changed the "=" to "in" as some of the others suggested. Would it be better to implement it with a JOIN? Why did you add the DISTINCT?

Answer (score 0):

use 'in' instead of equal symbol

```
SELECT employee.first_name, employee.last_name
FROM employee
WHERE employee.employee_id in 
(SELECT competences.employee_id
FROM competences
WHERE service_id = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the IN instead of "="

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM employee
WHERE employee_id IN (SELECT employee_id
                        FROM competences
                       WHERE service_id = 2)
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks. I felt like there should be an easy way to do it.